# Grails HQL representation of a query

Tags: mysql, grails, hql, grails-orm

I'm stuck representing in HQL the following MySQL query

```
SELECT t1.id as user_id, t2.id as follow_id
FROM user t1
INNER JOIN follows t2 ON 
    (t2.follower_id = <user id> AND t2.followee_id = t1.id) OR
    (t2.follower_id = t1.id AND t2.followee_id = <user id>)
WHERE t1.active = true
ORDER BY t1.id
```

Can you please help me out with the representation?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

So far I've tried the following HQL query, but it fails to return the proper data:

```
SELECT t1
FROM User t1
JOIN t1.follows t2
JOIN t2.follower follower
JOIN t2.followee followee
WHERE (follower.id = :usr AND followee.id = t1.id) OR
    (follower.id = t1.id AND followee.id = :usr) 
    AND t1.active = true
ORDER BY t1.id
```

The idea is that I have two tables:

```
User table:
+------+--------+-------------+
|  id  | name   | last_name   |
+------+--------+-------------+
| 1    | Jhon   | Doe         |
| 2    | Jane   | Doe         |
| 3    | Alfred | Hitchcock   |
+------+--------+-------------+
```

```
Follows table:
+------+-------------+-------------+
|  id  | follower_id | followee_id |
+------+-------------+-------------+
| 1    | 1           | 3           |
| 2    | 3           | 2           |
| 3    | 2           | 1           |
+------+-------------+-------------+
```

What I need is, for example, obtain the name and last name of all users who follow or are being followed by, let's say, user id 1.

The SQL query I posted does exactly this, but I cannot seem to replicate the same behaviour in HQL.

**2nd Edit:**
My simplified domain classes are:

```
class User {
    String name
    String lastName
    ...
    static hasMany = [ follows: Follows ]
    static mappedBy = [ follows: 'follower' ]
}
```

And...

```
class Follows {
    User Followee
    ...
    static belongsTo = [follower: User]
}
```

Comment: @dmahapatro I've edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of simplicity and since I was only reading data, I ended up using Groovy SQL which is accepted by Grails and itself accepts the plain SQL query I included in my original post (and doesn't require to match any specific domain model, big plus for me in this scenario)

Here's a link to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html), I specifically used the rows(String sql, Map params) method definition to query de DB and return the data I was searching for.

For using groovy.sql.Sql in Grails, I recommend adding it as a bean to the resources.groovy file:

```
beans = {

    groovySql(groovy.sql.Sql, ref('dataSource'))

}
```

and then inject the same into wherever you wanna use it:

```
class MyService {

    def groovySql
    ...

    def myMethod() {

        String query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE ..."

        Map params = [param1: p1]

        List<GroovyRowResult> result = groovySql.rows(query, params)

        ...

    }

}
```

Hope this helps anyone trying to perform plain SQL queries without the hassle of having to convert them to HQL or Criteria.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing to keep in mind when writing HQL queries is that **domain class** joins (HQL deals with domain classes, not tables) are completely reliant on the domain class associations. To put it differently, the associations actually create the (inner) joins, but HQL allows you to change the join *type* (LEFT OUTER, RIGHT OUTER, and Cartesian). See my [from clause](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-from-clause/) article.

I attempted to derive your domain class associations from your HQL and table descriptions and it just doesn't match up. But here's another way to do it.

## Domain model

The domain model is very simple. There's a `User` class containing a *one-to-many* association to itself (but it's not a self-join, as you'll see in a moment).

```
class User {
    String name
    String lastName

    static hasMany = [followees: User]  
}
```

Lets say you have a `User` instance.

```
def user = User.get(1)
```

`user.followees` contains the `User`s being *followed by* `user`.

## Table schema

With such a domain model the tables would look something like this:

### user table

```
+------+--------+-------------+
|  id  | name   | last_name   |
+------+--------+-------------+
| 1    | John   | Doe         |
| 2    | Jane   | Doe         |
| 3    | Alfred | Hitchcock   |
+------+--------+-------------+
```

### user_followees table

```
+-----------+-------------------+
|  user_id  | followees_user_id |
+-----------+-------------------+
| 1         | 2                 |
| 3         | 1                 |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

The data demonstrated suggests that:

1. John Doe *follows* Jane Doe.
2. Jane Doe is *followed by* John Doe.
3. Alfred Hitchcock *follows* John Doe.
4. John Doe is *followed by* Alfred Hitchcock.

This simple *one-to-many* association can be used to model the two-way relationship that is known as *following*. The same could be done with two *one-to-many* associations, which would simplify querying but complicate data maintenance. With this model the two-way *following* relationships are maintained with a single `user.addToFollowee()` or `user.removeFromFollowee()`.

## Querying

Using the domain model I described, you can query for followees and followers. Given a `user`...

```
def followees = user.followees // <-- contains Jane Doe

def followers = User.executeQuery 
    'SELECT u FROM User as u INNER JOIN u.followees as followee WHERE followee = :user',
    [user: user] // <-- contains Alfred Hithchcock

def following = followees + followers
```

Note that GORM/Hibernate does not support SQL's *UNION* clause, so you'll need two queries. See my [where clause](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-where-clause/) article for more details on GORM's equivalent of the where clause.

### Followers

It's also possible to use a **where** or **criteria** query to get the followers:

```
def followers = User.where { followees.id == user.id }.list()
def followers = User.withCriteria { followees { eq 'id', user.id } }
```

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, check the update to my question. The main reason I use a second domain called Follows it's because there's much more data involved into determine if the *follow* relationship is valid (for example: *Follows* domain class has a property called *blocked* and another one called *blocker* which determines if an user blocked another one and in which direction the blocking occurred).

Comment: You can still use a similar technique. You would still need two queries. Following: `SELECT follow FROM User as u INNER JOIN u.follows as follow WHERE u = :user`. Followers: `SELECT u FROM User as u INNER JOIN u.follows as followee WHERE followee = :user`. Just add your additional criteria to the *where* clause.